# issue on creating package

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

> Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors. BEGIN
>
> - ERROR at line 1: ORA-04063: package body "P13279.EMP_DESIGNATION" has errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being
>   called: "P13279.EMP_DESIGNATION" ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: ORA-06512 is part of the error stack. It gives us the line number where the exception occurred, but not the cause of the exception. Therefore, please update question with full code.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing a program unit (procedure, function, package) which either doesn't exist, or - if it exists but is owned by someone else - you don't have privileges to access it.